MaxListenersExceededWarning in discord.js despite only having one listener
I am creating a Discord bot using discord.js. One of the bot's commands requires it to send a large number of DMs to various different users.
Whenever that command is run, I get a MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
This is what my listener in index.js looks like:
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return;
  
  const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/);
  const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const updateTime = format(
    utcToZonedTime(new Date(new Date().getTime()), "Etc/UTC"),
    "h:mm:ss a zzz",
    { timeZone: "Etc/UTC" }
  );

  const user = {
    updateTime,
    isAuthorized,
    isOwner: message.author.id === OWNER,
  };

  const command =
    client.commands.get(commandName) ||
    client.commands.find(
      (cmd) => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName)
    );

  if (command) {
    try {
      await command.execute(message, args, user);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      message.channel.send(
        errorMessage(`There was an error trying to execute \`${commandName}\`.`)
      );
    }
  } else {
    message.channel.send(
      errorMessage(
        `Unknown command: "${command}". Please use \`${PREFIX}info\` to find a list of commands.`
      )
    );
  }
});

And this is what my "sending DM" function looks like, which is run on a loop several times when one of the commands is executed:
async function sendDM(message, game, dmText, id) {
  let player_disc;
  if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
    const guild = await message.client.guilds.cache.get(game.guild_id);
    player_disc = await guild.members.fetch(`${id}`).catch(() => null);
    if (!player_disc) return message.channel.send("User not found:(");
  } else {
    player_disc = await message.guild.members.fetch(`${id}`).catch(() => null);
    if (!player_disc) return message.channel.send("User not found:(");
  }
  await player_disc.send(dmText).catch(() => {
    message.channel.send(
      "User has DMs closed or has no mutual servers with the bot:("
    );
  });
}

I tried adding client.setMaxListeners(0); to my index.js file after I define const client = new Discord.Client();, but this did not do anything to help, the same error resulted.
